Matplotlib Histogram data automatically grouped
Normal-Distribution
A normal distribution is generated as seen below.
Image
It works by working out the amount of times heads is flipped when you flip the coin 10 times.
It then repeats 10 flips 100K times.
The result is a normal distribution showing the distribution of values as a histogram.
Image1
Image2
Read README ...
Issue:
Plotted graph using matplotlib isn't smooth I havent set a value for the bin values (x axis).
(See above)
Image3
I've tried increasing the amount of trials. eg 100 Flips done 100K times but it still looks fixed like blocks not fluid like a normal distribution.
Image 4
I cant post images but if you check the github yashGaneshgudi it mathches the issue...
Thanks
https://github.com/yashGaneshgudi/Normal-Distribution
UPDATE ADDED CODE
import random
results=[]

for i in range (100000):
    heads=0
    print(i)

    for i in range(10):
        coin = random.randint(0, 1)
        if coin == 1:
            heads += 1
    results.append(heads)
    print(heads)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(results)
plt.show()


results can only take integer values between 0 and 10. There is no way that it could produce a smooth histogram, since there are only eleven possible values for the data.
Try adding more coin flips, e.g.
import random
results=[]

for i in range (100000):
    heads=0
    print(i)

    for i in range(1000):
        coin = random.randint(0, 1)
        if coin == 1:
            heads += 1
    results.append(heads)
    print(heads)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(results, bins=50)
plt.show()

This will produce a smoother plot, but there will be periodic spikes. Reason why is left as an exercise. (Hint: think about where the bin lines are placed)

Hint: calculate adequate bin edges instead of relying on the default ones, which are meant for continuous data.

@JohanC Makes sense now that im thinking about that.I just assumed the default settings would not manipulate the data as much. Thanks for the response

Thanks dawson-beatty for the quick response. It takes quite a bit longer but works.I'm guessing the bins seperate the data if you get what I mean.So more bins more Intervals so it looks better.                                                                                                                              I'm unsure why the result is quite staggered with random spikes and doesnt completely follow a normal distribution.Surely theres some million coin flips that it should just even out.Is it due to at that scale pythons random function isnt as random.I cant think of anything else ...

I think i worded the question disgustingly im getting so many downvotes ?!?!

`import random
results=[]
for i in range (100000):
heads=0
print(i)
for i in range(1000):
coin = random.randint(0, 1)
if coin == 1:
heads += 1
results.append(heads)
print(heads)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(results,bins=500)
plt.show()`

I halved Intervals and it produces a great graph see https://github.com/yashGaneshgudi/Normal-Distribution Thanks for the help!

One more question why does the graph have thick lines? surely all intervals lines should be the same.maybe its the formatting too many bins and it all just breaks after like 10?

I'm not sure what you mean about "thick lines"
